# Find content between HTML tags using RegEx

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, regex

I want to extract content of a page which has the attribute name `itemprop`. Suppose I have page which has different HTML tags that have the attribute named `itemprop` so I want text in between those tags,

For a heading:

```
<h1 itemprop="name" class="h2">Whirlpool Direct Drive Washer Motor Coupling</h1>
```

Table data from td tag:

```
<td itemprop="productID">AP3963893</td>
```

Here the `itemprop` attribute is common. So I need data in between these tags like `Whirlpool Direct Drive Washer Motor Coupling` and `AP3963893` using regexp .

Below is my code (which is currently not working)

```
preg_match_all(
    '/<div class=\"pdct\-inf\">(.*?)<\/div>/s',
    $producturl,
    $posts    
);
```

My code:

```
<?php
    define('CSV_PATH','csvfiles/');
    $csv_file = CSV_PATH . "producturl.csv"; // Name of your producturl file
    $csvfile = fopen($csv_file, 'r');
    $csv_fileoutput = CSV_PATH . "productscraping.csv"; // Name of your product page data file
    $csvfileoutput = fopen($csv_fileoutput, 'a');

    $websitename = "http://www.appliancepartspros.com";

    while($data = fgetcsv($csvfile)) 
    {
        $producturl = $websitename . trim($data[1]);

        preg_match_all(
            '/<.*itemprop=\".*\".*>(.*?)<\/.*>/s',
            $producturl,
            $posts    
        );
        print_r($posts);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, [never ever use RegEx to parse HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags). Secondly, you can achieve this using jQuery quite simply by using the attribute selector:

```
var nameItemprop = $('[itemprop="name"]').text(); // = 'Whirlpool Direct Drive Washer Motor Coupling'
var productIdItemprop = $('[itemprop="productID"]').text(); // = 'AP3963893'
```

Note however, that it is invalid HTML to create your own non-standard attributes. You should ideally be using `data-*` attributes to contain data associated with those elements:

```
<h1 data-itemprop="name" class="h2">Whirlpool Direct Drive Washer Motor Coupling</h1>
<td data-itemprop="productID">AP3963893</td>
```

```js
var nameItemprop = $('[data-itemprop="name"]').text();
var productIdItemprop = $('[data-itemprop="productID"]').text();
```

Finally, should there ever be multiple elements with the same `itemprop` attribute then you would need to loop through them to get the value from each individual element.

Comment: can you please suggest me php example using regexp, because as there are lot of product url which is store in csv file.

Comment: Sorry, I don't know PHP. As you tagged jQuery I used that.

Comment: Updated my question with my code .. please have a look

Answer (score 0):

As already mentioned, you shouldn't use RegExp to parse HTML, but if you insist on doing it, here's a pattern that should work:

```
$producturl = '<h1 itemprop="name" class="h2">Whirlpool Direct Drive Washer Motor Coupling</h1>';

if (preg_match_all(
   '/<.*itemprop=\".*\".*>(.*?)<\/.*>/s',
   $producturl,
   $posts    
)) {
    print_r($posts);
}
```

This creates the following output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => <h1 itemprop="name" class="h2">Whirlpool Direct Drive Washer Motor Coupling</h1>
        )
    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => Whirlpool Direct Drive Washer Motor Coupling
        )
)
```

Comment: it returns blank array.. I have updated my code in question .. please have a look.

Comment: I've added a complete example so you can copy, paste and execute it. That works for me..

Comment: you are passing html content to producturl variable, but in my case its a absolute url ..